# getting ids of multiple rows inserted in psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I'd like to use psycopg2 to `INSERT` multiple rows and then return all the `id`s (in order) using a single query. This is what PostgreSQL's `RETURNING` extension is designed for, and it seems to work fine using `cursor.execute`:

```
cursor.execute(
    "INSERT INTO my_table (field_1, field_2) "
    "VALUES (0, 0), (0, 0) RETURNING id;"
)
print cursor.fetchall()

[(1,), (2,)]
```

Now, in order to pass in dynamically-generated data, it seems like `cursor.executemany` is the way to go:

```
data = [(0, 0), (0, 0)]

cursor.executemany(
    "INSERT INTO my_table (field_1, field_2) "
    "VALUES (%s, %s) RETURNING id;",
    data
)
```

However, in that case, `cursor.fetchall()` produces the following:

```
[(4,), (None,)]
```

How do I get it to correctly return all the `id`s instead of just the one?

Comment: Interesting problem. psycopg2 version, and underlying PostgreSQL version client-side?

Comment: psycopg2 2.4.5 (dt dec pq3 ext) and PostgreSQL 9.2.4

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're not supposed to be able to get results from `executemany`:

> The function is mostly useful for commands that update the database: any result set returned by the query is discarded.

Per [the psycopg2 docs](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html).

You'll be better off looping over a single `insert` within a transaction, or using a multi-valued `insert... returning`, though in the latter case you must be careful to match returned IDs using another input value, you can't just assume the order of returned IDs is the same as the input `VALUES` list.

When I run your test locally, it simply fails:

```
>>> import psycopg2
>>> conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=regress")
>>> curs = conn.cursor()
>>> curs.execute("create table my_table(id serial primary key, field_1 integer, field_2 integer);")
>>> data = [(0, 0), (0, 0)]
>>> curs.executemany(
...     "INSERT INTO my_table (field_1, field_2) "
...     "VALUES (%s, %s) RETURNING id;",
...     data
... )
>>> 
>>> curs.fetchall()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: no results to fetch
```

Tested with psycopg2 2.5.1.

Comment: Thanks! I was completely unaware of `RETURNING`'s order being non-guaranteed. Unfortunately, I have no way of uniquely matching returned `id`s. Any ideas on how to proceed in that case (beyond just inserting a dummy unique field)?

Comment: @Jian If you need to associate a returned generated ID with an inserted tuple, you'll need to just insert them one by one, or use `returning *` and match the whole inserted tuple. (Pg currently does return IDs in the order the inputs appear in the `values` clause, but it might stop doing that in future, and the SQL spec doesn't require it to).

Comment: @CraigRinger, can you point to the PostgreSQL docs where it says whether or not the rows returned by RETURNING are in order of the VALUES you gave? It would be a real pain if this isn't guaranteed.

Comment: That's the point - it doesn't explicitly guarantee it anywhere, and in SQL everything is an unordered set unless specifically ordered. Reasons why `RETURNING` order could change would be things like support for index-ordered tables being introduced. It might be a good idea to raise the question on pgsql-general though - it's possible the SQL spec its self provides such a guarantee, in which case Pg must honour it. Right now, it seems to work just because the implementation will consume and emit rows in the order they're presented as input.

Answer (score 5):

The trick is to use mogrify. It uses a single execute and id therefore faster than executemany anyways:

```
def insert_many(self, table: str, id_column: str, values: list):
    if not values:
        return []

    keys = values[0].keys()
    query = cursor.mogrify("INSERT INTO {} ({}) VALUES {} RETURNING {}".format(
            table,
            ', '.join(keys),
            ', '.join(['%s'] * len(values)),
            id_column
        ), [tuple(v.values()) for v in values])

    conn = psycopg2.connect("host=localhost4 port=5432 dbname=cpn")
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute(query)
    return [t[0] for t in (cursor.fetchall()]
```

Answer (score 4):

Pass the dynamically-generated data as an array of tuples and unnest it

```
import psycopg2

insert = """
    insert into my_table (field_1, field_2)
    select field_1, field_2
    from unnest(%s) s(field_1 int, field_2 int)
    returning id
;"""

data = [(0,0),(1,1),(2,2)]

conn = psycopg2.connect("host=localhost4 port=5432 dbname=cpn")
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute(insert, (data,))
print cursor.fetchall()
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Prints

```
[(1,), (2,), (3,)]
```

Comment: Nice! I was wondering how to accept dynamically generated data without resorting to Python string formatting, and this does just that. But what if you don't know the field names in advance because they are also dynamically generated? Is there a clean psycopg2 API for formatting those?

Comment: Only works when all of the data is of similar types. If you try to mix numeric and textual types this can not work.