# Sqlalchemy insert query does not return results

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, psycopg2

I have tried to select returning values from insert query:

```
HOST_INSERT_QUERY = (
    Host.__table__.insert()
        .values(
            name=bindparam("name"),
            source=bindparam("source"),
            type=bindparam("type")
                )
        .returning(Host.__table__.c.id)
)
result = db_conn.execute(HOST_INSERT_QUERY, values)
```

What I see from db.echo:

```
info sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine INSERT INTO hosts (name, source, type) VALUES ( %(name)s, %(source)s, %(type)s) RETURNING hosts.id
info sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ({ 'name': 'hhh', 'source': '["import"]', 'type': 'host'},{...})
debug:  Added 2 hosts
```

It really works. Hosts inserts into database, but I see some troubles in debugger; result (ResultProxy) has:

```
rowcount = 2 #right!
is_insert = True #right!
return_rows=False #WHYYYY????????
```

If I try to:

```
result.fetсhall()

AttributeError: 'ResultProxy' object has no attribute 'fetсhall'
```

Versions:

- SQLAlchemy 1.3.1
- psycopg-binary 2.7.7

Note!
This code only works when inserting a single record. When inserting multiple lines, it is not possible to pull the values ​​out of the RETURNING.

Comment: The cursor may have been read prior to invoking `fetchall` method on it. Nothing seems curious about the query.

Comment: Maybe.  result = db_conn.execute(HOST_INSERT_QUERY, values)
In this case, a more appropriate error message is obtained: AttributeError: 'ResultProxy' object has no attribute 'fetсhall'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[You cannot get results from `executemany`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21624844/getting-ids-of-multiple-rows-inserted-in-psycopg2), which SQLAlchemy uses underneath if you pass a set of more than 1 row to insert. That's why you observe `return_rows=False`. A workaround is to "inline" the rows using one multi `VALUES` clause, instead of using bindparams and `executemany`:

```
HOST_INSERT_QUERY = (
    Host.__table__.insert()
        .values(values)
        .returning(Host.__table__.c.id)
)

result = db_conn.execute(HOST_INSERT_QUERY)
```

This executes as a single "multi values" statement and so avoids using `executemany`, and may return results. Note that the order of the returned IDs may not match that of the inserted rows.